# Typeahead.js displaying only 5 options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

How to increase the number of options in typeahead?

Below is my code:

```
    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;

        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });

        cb(matches);
    };
};

$(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("getApplications")',function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
        $('#the-basics #Appl_ShortName_textbox').typeahead(
        {
            hint: false,
            highlight: false,
            minLength: 1,
            minLimit: 10,
            maxLimit: 10
        },
    {
        name: 'data',
        source: substringMatcher(data)
    });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

under "source: substringMatcher(data)" add "limit: (whatever you want the max # of items to show)".

for example:

```
 source: substringMatcher(data),
 limit: 20
```

would result in a dropdown menu with max 20 items.